# How can I view the pdf file in Django?

Tags: python, django

**Note:**

1. My model table consists of id field and File field which will be pdf.
2. I am inserting data into the model using django admin.(I have no custom upload form)
3. I am trying to view the pdf in the browser(as it normally opens in chrome).
4. I am trying to find the file by taking the id field(by user) in a custom HTML template using a form(Please look at the codes mentioned below.)
5. I am attaching the urls.py, index.html, views.py, models.py and forms.py codes below. Please patiently go through and let me the know the problem and the solution.
6. I think my code should work but I am getting a Suspicious File Operation Error.

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('',views.index),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

**views.py**

```
def index(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = Form(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            id=request.POST.get("id")
            ans = query.objects.get(id=id)
            response=ans.repo
            if ans is None:
                return redirect("index.html")
            else:
                #return render (request,"ans.html",{'ans':response})
                return redirect(response)
    else:
        form = Form()
    return render(request,"index.html",{'form':form})
```

**forms.py**

```
class Form(forms.Form):
    id = forms.CharField(label="Report ID", max_length=100)
```

**models.py**

```
class query(models.Model):
    id=models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    repo=models.FileField(upload_to='documents/')
```

**index.html**

```
<!-- Search Form -->
        <form id="signup-form" method="POST" action="">
        {% csrf_token %}
            {{form}}
            <input type="submit" value="Check" />
        </form>
```

Comment: @Rarblack
you have my whole code now. Please help me accordingly.

Comment: Nothing in your code appears to deal  PDFs. Where is that coming from?

Comment: Can you also mention what error you are getting

Comment: @bharatbhushan My code is taking me to the url of the file present such as "localhost:8000/documents/file.pdf" but I am getting the error of suspicious file action at.....

Comment: @TahseenRahman this problem is only occurs to you in chrome, then may be popup file blocked is enabled in firefox

Comment: @DanielRoseman I want to view the pdf which is stored in the repo field of query model. And you don't see code to deal with pdf because I don't know how to. See the views.py code where I am searching for id in the query model and response variable contains repo field connected with that id. And from there I am trying to view the pdf.

Comment: @bharatbhushan Is there a way I could make it work. I want to have this project in production. So it's important for me. I believe it is happening because I want to access the file in the database directly through the URL. Is there a way to do it with views?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The URL for a file field is in the `url` attribute, so you need to use `ans.repo.url`.

Comment: My url for file should be "localhost:8000/documents/file.pdf" but it is navigating to "localhost/documents/documents/file.pdf". Can you tell me why?

The exception value is: 
The joined path (E:\Work in Progress\Python\Delhi_patho\delhi_patho\documents\Resume.pdf) is located outside of the base path component (E:\Work in Progress\Python\Delhi_patho\delhi_patho\) @bharat bhushan